# What is an InstallationID in Quickbooks QBMSXML

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have a qbmsxml that I'm sending that continues to get a response error 2000.

```
<qbmsxml>
  <signonmsgsrq>
    <signondesktoprq>
      <clientdatetime>2014-04-03T09:37:23</clientdatetime>
      <applicationlogin>my.application.login.id</applicationlogin>
      <connectionticket>SDK-MY-Connection-Ticket</connectionticket>
      <language>English</language>
      <appid>9999999999</appid>
      <appver>1.0</appver>
    </signondesktoprq>
  </signonmsgsrq>
  <qbmsxmlmsgsrq>
    <customercreditcardauthrq>
      <transrequestid>140403937231</transrequestid>
      <creditcardnumber>4111111111111111</creditcardnumber>
      <expirationmonth>12</expirationmonth>
      <expirationyear>2017</expirationyear>
      <isecommerce>true</isecommerce>
      <amount>0.01</amount>
      <nameoncard>John Doe</nameoncard>
      <creditcardaddress>1234 Main Street</creditcardaddress>
      <creditcardpostalcode>12345</creditcardpostalcode>
    </customercreditcardauthrq>
  </qbmsxmlmsgsrq>
</qbmsxml>
```

As I've been reviewing the information on creating a request, I found an 'InstallationID' tag referenced. It goes in the  element like so:

```
  <signonmsgsrq>
    <signondesktoprq>
      <clientdatetime>2014-04-03T09:37:23</clientdatetime>
      <applicationlogin>my.application.login.id</applicationlogin>
      <connectionticket>SDK-MY-Connection-Ticket</connectionticket>
      <installationid>IDTYPE</installationid>
      <language>English</language>
      <appid>9999999999</appid>
      <appver>1.0</appver>
    </signondesktoprq>
  </signonmsgsrq>
```

My question is: What is the IDTYPE for InstallationID? Where can I get it? What options can I set it to?

Comment: Where are you seeing this request?

Comment: You should post the *actual error message* and *http response* you're getting back from Intuit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not related to your `InstallationID` field at all. I think the problem is that your XML isn't conforming to what Intuit expects.

Specifically, everything in your XML request is lowercase, when Intuit expects it to be camel case. You're also missing a qbmsxml version header, and a xml version header.

Here's an example of a correctly formed request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbmsxml version="3.0"?>
<QBMSXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonTicketRq>
            <ClientDateTime>2009-10-09T13:14:16</ClientDateTime>
            <SessionTicket>xxxxxxxxxxxxky4yL6eBtCULX1zgQ:106892184</SessionTicket>
        </SignonTicketRq>
    </SignonMsgsRq>
    <QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
        <CustomerCreditCardChargeRq>
            <TransRequestID>35f9cf7cb20994e8a32e6b3e91e8e602</TransRequestID>
            <CreditCardNumber>xxxxxxxxxxxx5100</CreditCardNumber>
            <ExpirationMonth>10</ExpirationMonth>
            <ExpirationYear>2009</ExpirationYear>
            <Amount>295.00</Amount>
            <NameOnCard>Keith Palmer</NameOnCard>
            <CreditCardAddress>56 Cowles Road</CreditCardAddress>
            <CreditCardPostalCode>06279</CreditCardPostalCode>
        </CustomerCreditCardChargeRq>
    </QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBMSXML>
```

Where are you getting your syntax from? It seems very wrong... here are some good examples:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbms_integration